# Java application that prints its own source code

Tags: java, quine

I have a little quiz that I cannot solve by myself.
I want to build a program that will print its own source code with java. Anyone knows how to do this?
Like this example:

```
public class SourcePrint {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void test(){
        System.out.println("Hi I'm test");

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SourcePrint().test();
    }

}
```

when we run this, the output would be same like this:

```
public class SourcePrint {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void test(){
        System.out.println("Hi I'm test");

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SourcePrint().test();
    }

}
```

I don't know how to do this. Anybody know the solution or at least the hint? This is not the decompiler, the quiz maker told me the hint is "STATIC".

Comment: Quines generally involve printing the source without reading it in from its own source file, which is regarded as cheating [in regards to this kind of problem]. Does your solution requirement specify whether you allowed to do this?

Answer (score 6):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29

Comment: A link is not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example that may be of use for Quine in java:

```
public class Quine {

    static String s = "public class Quine { public static void main(String[] args) { char c=34; System.out.println(s+c+s+c+';'+'}'); } static String s=";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char c = 34;
        System.out.println(s + c + s + c + ';' + '}');
    }
}
```

and of course the seemingly mandatory link to Wikipedia: [Wikipedia: Quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29). depending on how large the program is this link here may also have some good examples: [Java Quine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120505011341/http://cs.utsa.edu/~mshonle/JavaQuine.html)

Comment: Last link is broken, please fix.

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.io.*;  
class Source  
{  
    public static void main(String args[])  
    {  
        try{  

            //open the file  
        FileInputStream fstream=new FileInputStream("D://Springs WorkSpace/Testing/src/Source.java");//here pass the own java file name with full path 

            // use DataInputStream to read binary NOT text  
        // DataInputStream in=new DataInputStream(fstream);  

            //  
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));  
            //read data line by line from the file  
            String s;  
            while((s = br.readLine() ) != null)  
            {  
                System.out.println(s);  
            }  
            in.close();  
        }  
        catch(Exception e){  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

a quick google search turned up the following link:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29

the type of program you are looking for is generally referred to as a quine.